# Is there a "cases" environment in text mode?

Tags: math-mode, cases, text-mode

The title says it all: The "cases" environment works only in math mode. Is there an alternative in text mode?

Comment: Are you referring to the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) `cases` environment, or those provided by [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools): `dcases`, `rcases`, ... And I assume by "text mode" you're referring to "inline math mode"?

Comment: By "cases" environment I mean "cases" environment, and by text mode I mean text mode, the mode you are in by default if you don't open a `$` or a `\[`.

Comment: So you just want to type `Some text \begin{cases} ... \end{cases} some more text` and it should automatically switch to math mode and back?

Answer (score 5):

You can emulate a `cases` environment for text mode using a `\parbox` or a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\Text{text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text }

\begin{document}

\[
\left\lbrace\parbox{7cm}{\Text}\right.
\]

\[
\left\lbrace
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{6cm}p{4cm}} 
\Text & \Text\Text \\
\Text & \Text\Text 
\end{tabular}\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `cases` environment works without modification in inline math mode. That is, the following works:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
...
Some interesting text $P_{r-j}=\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}$ and more interesting text.
```

However, if need be, you could just create your own using an `array` in inline math mode. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
Some interesting text 
$P_{r-j}=\left\{\def\arraystretch{1.2}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}
  $0$ & if $r-j$ is odd \\
  $r!((-1)^{(r-j)/2}$ & if $r-j$ is even.
\end{tabular}\right.$ 
Of course, this will modify the baseline compared to the display format:
\[
  P_{r-j}=\begin{cases}
      0 & \text{if $r-j$ is odd} \\
      r!((-1)^{(r-j)/2} & \text{if $r-j$ is even.}
    \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

The definitions within the `tabular` environment (resetting `\arraystretch` to `1.2` and the column alignment/specification `@{}l@{\quad}l@{}`) were taken directly from the definitions of the `cases` environment in the [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)

[image: Cases in inline math mode and displaystyle math mode]

Comment: Of course it works in inline. But I want to get rid of the `\text`, which is why I want it to work in text mode.

Comment: Using `tabular` instead of `array` in my example above you could get rid of `\text`. However, then the left column needs `$...$`.

Answer (score 1):

you can define the height by the number of lines, in this case 11

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}

\newcommand\Text{text text text text text text text 
text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text }

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l p{6cm} }
\ldelim\{{11}{1.5cm}[Left Side ]
  & \Text\Text \\
  & \Text
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]